# How can I merge client's information with 2 IDs to only one ID in SQL database?

Tags: sql-server

I have a client who signed up using Email and then PhoneNumber, search their name on the Database there's 2 IDs for same client. How can I merge the client's info to 1 ID? I am not allowed to SET IDENTITY COLUMN OFF/ON as this would break the database

Comment: At a business level this sounds like a manual, non-generic operation.  One which can be automated, but would need to have the business logic of that automation.  From the description I would say it's likely that you would update one record to have the additional data from the other record, then delete the other record.  But it's up to your business needs to determine what specific data to update, if child records need to be re-parented, what implications these changes might have, etc.  But ultimately it doesn't sound like this has anything to do with *the identity column* specifically.

Comment: _I am not allowed to SET IDENTITY COLUMN OFF/ON as this would break the database_ No it will NOT break the database. But since you have restrictions, have you considered asking / consulting with the rest of your team to find an appropriate solution? The simple solution is to update all the rows that refer to one ID by setting that reference to the other ID. Then you just delete the old ID. And perhaps now is a good time to revisit the lack of natural key enforcement so that "names" can be duplicated.

Comment: @David and SMor thanks for your timely replies. And yes it turns out I just needed to update all the rows that refer to one ID to the other across multiple tables on the database and that solved the problem for me.